# Navigation Drawer Menu Scroll Effect

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design, android-navigationview

I'm using NavigationView in DrawerLayout for my app's navigation menu here's the xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/textColor"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/textColor"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The problem: I don't even have enough items to scroll but I'm seeing this effect while trying to scroll, I want to disable this effect, thank you.
[Scrolling effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peXSn.png)

**Update**

trying both:

```
android:overScrollMode "never" in NavigationView
```

and

```
navigationView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
```

didn't work.

I'm calling following method in `onCreate()` :

```
public void setupDrawerLayout() {
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolBar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    drawerToggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You are trying to disable the scrolling shadow.
Try adding this to your `NavigationView`:

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

If the above solution doesn't work, try adding this in the `onCreate()` method of your Activity or wherever you setup your UI:

```
mNavigationView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
```

**UPDATE**

After some more testing I found that indeed, the solutions posted in the answers so far are not working. However, I found this to work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < navigationView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    navigationView.getChildAt(i).setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}
```

Add it in your `onCreate()` method, after you initialise the navigation drawer.

Comment: It didn't work, I've added this for both `NavigationView` and `DrawerLayout` on different builds, still seeing that scrolling shadow @Bandreid

Comment: I'll prefer using `ifContentScrolls` instead of `never` if in case OP adds new items in the future.

Comment: In my experience, using `ifContentScrolls` will still show a scroll shadow if the content is in a scrollable container, even if it doesn't fill the vertical space.